# Empty result with first alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to retrieve json response and below code snippet shows the way I've implemented it.The problem I'm having there is at the first attempt I can't fetch data through an alert. Actually it gives me an empty result. But once I added another alert right after the previous alert it gives me the out-come from the second alert. I can't figure out the reason for this.

My code :

```
            var sales = [];
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getSalesAction',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        var weekDaySale = {day: value.day,
                            amount: value.amount
                        };
                        sales.push(weekDaySale);

                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
            alert(sales);//first alert (returns empty alert)
            alert(sales); //second alert.( returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]])
```

What is the reason for not giving the out-put from the first alert ?. Thank you.

Comment: In the time it takes to operate the mouse to click on the alert, you'll (usually) have recieved the HTTP response.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous

Comment: @Quentin I actually need to attach my response to a chart . But without alert chart appears empty. but with the alert it works.

Comment: @SteveSilva — See the duplicate question